# Isomorphic Vector Spaces of infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have equal algebraic dimension.

The infinite case is needed here as well.

Comment: Can you do the finite dimensional case? What were the necessary features? Can you extend them to infinite dimensions if you're careful?

Comment: Not really sure how to approach this at all.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose $f\colon V\to W$ is an isomorphism. If $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis of $V$, then
>   $$
> f[\mathscr{B}]=\{f(v):v\in\mathscr{B}\}
> $$
>   is a basis of $W$.

*Proof.* Suppose $\sum_{v\in\mathscr{B}}\alpha_vf(v)=0$. Then
$$
f\Bigl(\,\sum_{v\in\mathscr{B}}\alpha_v v\Bigr)=0
$$
so $\sum_{v\in\mathscr{B}}\alpha_v v=0$ and therefore $\alpha_v=0$, for every $v\in\mathscr{B}$. This proves linear independence.

If $y\in W$, then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in V$. Hence $x=\sum_{v\in\mathscr{B}}\alpha_v v$ for a suitable choice of scalars. Therefore
$$
y=f(x)=\sum_{v\in\mathscr{B}}\alpha_v f(v)
$$
This proves $f[\mathscr{B}]$ is a spanning set of $W$. QED

**Note.** In the above, when $\sum_{v\in\mathscr{B}}\alpha_v v$ or similar summation is considered, all scalars $\alpha_v$ are zero for all but a finite number of summands.

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension. Then $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

*Sketch of proof.* There are bases $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ of $V$ and $W$, respectively, and a bijection $\varphi\colon\mathscr{B}\to\mathscr{C}$. Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis of $V$, such a map extends uniquely to a linear map $\hat\varphi\colon V\to W$ which is an isomorphism (injectivity is proved with the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is linearly independent, surjectivity with the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is a spanning set).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to prove the following lemma yourself for finite dimensions.

Lemma: A $K$-linear map $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ is an isomorphism of finite dimensional vector spaces iff for any basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ of $V$, $\{\phi(v_1),\cdots,\phi(v_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Then see if you can use the same trick for infinite dimensions. There's a subtlety in the lemma hidden in the $n$ -- both spaces must have a basis of the same cardinality.

Edit: A proof of the lemma.

Suppose $\phi$ is an isomorphism. We want to see $\{\phi(v_i)\}$ is a basis. If they are not linearly independent, then without loss of generality we have: $$\phi(v_1) = \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i\phi(v_i) = \sum_{i=2}^n \phi(\lambda_iv_i) = \phi\left( \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i v_i\right)$$ but since $\phi$ is 1-1 we have $v_1 = \sum_{i=2}^n \lambda_i v_i$, a contradiction as $\{v_i\}$ is a basis. Further, we have $\{\phi(v_i)\}$ spans $W$ as $\phi$ is onto, since for any $w \in W$, we $w = \phi(v)$ for some $v$, and since $v = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i$, so by linearity we have $w = \sum_i \lambda_i \phi(v_i)$ so that $\phi(v_i)$ span.

Further, the above works in reverse to show that if $\{\phi(v_i)\}$ is a basis then $\phi$ must be an isomorphism.

In infinite dimensions, the proof is very similar, since any vector in a vector space is a linear combination of only finitely many basis elements.

Comment: hmm. I dont see how this can be extended to infinite dimensions.

Comment: This is what I mentioned after -- the only thing we needed to use were that the bases have the same cardinality. For $V$ infinite dimensional, let, $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $V$. Then if $\phi(\mathcal{B})$ denotes the set $\{\phi(v) \mid v \in \mathcal{B}\}$, we should have $\phi(\mathcal{B})$ is a basis for $W$.

Comment: I see. Then I guess this lemma completes the proof for both the forwards and backwards directions then?

Comment: Well one should be careful to construct the $\phi$ in question when it's not given. Given a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$, if they have the same cardinality, then there is a bijection between them. Extending that bijection linearly you get the isomorphism.

Comment: How do we go about proving the lemma. I have been unable to make progress.